# indexing multiple keys for random queries in different combinations of keys

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding, nosql

I'm building an application that stores lots of data per user (possibly in gigabytes).

Something like a request log, so lets say you have the following fields for every record:

```
customer_id
date
hostname
environment
pid
ip
user_agent
account_id
user_id
module
action
id
response code
response time (range)
```

and possibly some more.

The good thing is that the usage will be mostly write only, but when there are reads
I'd like to be able to answer then quickly in near real time.

Another prediction about the usage pattern is that most of the time people will be looking at the most recent data,
and infrequently query for the past, aggregate etc, so my guess is that the working set will be much smaller then
the whole database, i.e. recent data for most users and ranges of history for some users that are doing analytics right now.
for the later case I suppose its ok for first query to be slower until it gets the range into memory.

But the problem is that Im not quite sure how to effectively index the data.

The start of the index is clear, its customer_id and date. but the rest can be
used in any combination and I can't predict the most common ones, at least not with any degree of certainty.

We are currently prototyping this with mongo. Is there a way to do it in mongo (storage/cpu/cost) effectively?

The only thing that comes to mind is to try to predict a couple of frequent queries and index them and just massively shard the data
and ensure that each customer's data is spread evenly over the shards to allow fast table scan over just the 'customer, date' index for the rest
of the queries.

P.S. I'm also open to suggestions about db alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this limited number of fields, you could potentially just have an index on each of them, or perhaps in combination with customer_id. MongoDB is clever enough to pick the fastest index for each case then. If you can fit your whole data set in memory (a few GB is not a lot of data!), then this all really doesn't matter.

You're saying you have a GB **per user**, but that still means you can have an index on the fields as there are only about a dozen. And with that much data, you want sharding anyway at some point soon.

cheers,
Derick

Comment: A few GB **per user**. We don't know how many users will he have. Maybe tens of thousands. That's a lot already.

Comment: Right, but you can still have an index on the fields as there are only about a dozen. And with that much data, you want sharding anyway at some point soon. (Added that to my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think, your requirements don't really mix well together. You can't have lots of data and instantaneous ad-hoc queries.

If you use a lot of indexes, then your writes will be slow, and you'll need **much** more RAM.

May I suggest this:

Keep your index on customer id and date to serve recent data to users and relax your requirements to either real-timeliness or accuracy of aggregate queries.

If you sacrifice accuracy, you will be firing map-reduce jobs every once in a while to precompute queries. Users then may see slightly stale data (or may not, it's historical immutable data, after all).

If you sacrifice speed, then you'll run map-reduce each time (right now it's the only sane way of calculating aggregates in a mongodb cluster).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "Will they query raw log entries? Doesn't look like an analytics system.": 

We are talking about request logs. You want to "tail" and paginate to see what happens to the system right now or at a certain point in time. and you want to slice and analyse them, like "what requests came from this ip" or what this user was doing in the system yesterday.

Comment: @VitalyKushner: I see now, thanks. Removed that part from the answer.

Comment: also "real-time" is probably too much for the needs. a few seconds of waiting for the "analytical" answers is ok. half a minute is not ok.

Comment: I'll definitely be doing some map reducing to aggregate metrics like average/max/min response times for graphs etc, but the basic analytics questions are hard to predict.

Comment: don't predict then. See what users are running and precalculate those :-)

Comment: Also, you can even have two systems. One for tailing and another for analytics. Classic OLTP/OLAP division